# Handling a callback URL in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF2 web application that i would like to receive some parameters from another web application.

```
Another application to redirect user to my JSF2 application using URL:
http://something.com/myjsf2app/getCallback.jsf?item=apple&color=green
```

I would like to know what i need to do to retrieve the following two values (item, color) in my backing bean without needing to hit on submit on getCallback.jsf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use viewparams to set the parameters in a @ViewScoped @ManagedBean

```
<h:body>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam id="item" name="item" value="#{myBean.item}"/>
        <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{myBean.init}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:body>
```

The view param is set after your beans @PostConstruct method is invoked. So if you want to do some stuff based on the value, use the event preRenderView

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for/6377957#6377957